# android unicode to readable string

Tags: java, android, string, unicode, textview

When I am reading some text from a web page, I get some problems with unicode chars displayed in TextView.

I am retrieving the web content by using the following code :

```
try {
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
    request.addHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    request.setURI(new URI(wwwlink));
    try {
        response4 = httpClient.execute(request);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {e.printStackTrace();}   
try {
    in2 = null;
    String UTF8 = "UTF-8";
    in2 = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(response4.getEntity().getContent(),UTF8));
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {Log.i(tag,e.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {Log.i(tag,e.toString());}
```

The page I am reading has this HTML heading tag :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

Now the problem is : I read lines and some text that I need contains unicode chars like that :

```
20 \u00b0C (20 degree symbol C )
```

I am trying to convert this and display as degree symbol in TextView.

The following is working

```
textview.settext("\u00b0");
```

But when I do that, the line contains unicode chars:

```
line = in2.readln;
textview.settext(line);
```

TextView will display f.e.: `some text \u00b0 some text`

I've checked everything with the emulator and a phone.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate. Search around on SO.

Comment: can`t find it ... like in python string.decode -> the same problem i think.

Answer (score 0):

As your input text contains java representation for unicode, you will need manually substitute such characters to correct ones. Here I give an example how tor replace one single char from the String just to give a rough idea:

```
    String input = "some text \\u00b0 some text";
    Scanner scanner =  new Scanner(input);
    String unicodeCharStr = scanner.findWithinHorizon("\\\\{1}u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}", 0);
    char unicodeChar = (char)(int)Integer.valueOf(unicodeCharStr.substring(2, 6), 16);
    input = input.replace(unicodeCharStr, unicodeChar+"");
```